# How to create a tilted slideshow

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel

I'm new to frontend coding and would like to know how I should approach creating a tilted slideshow that would go from text to image when hovering over.
[image: sorry for the bad sketch]

Thank you.

Comment: You can use bootstrap carousel sliders. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: @DhiaDjobbi Does carousel support being able to see the text from other slides at the same time viewing the current slide?

Comment: You need to start with CSS transforms, link to the visual example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Result

Comment: Also do *not* use bootstrap! If you plan on doing quality work learn the base languages and you'll be running circles around the people who don't understand the basics.

Comment: @John Thank you very much. This is exactly what I am looking for